# I can't access a queue from local Azure Storage Emulator nor from VisualStudio, nor from Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: windows, azure, storage, emulation, explorer

I need to send messages through an Azure Queue and I need to test it using the Windows Azure Emulator, which says to be correctly running. These are the steps I went through:

1- Running the Windows Azure Storage Emulator (I tried both 2.0.0 and 3.2.0 versions)
   Making sure the emulator is running:

- When using Windows Azure Storage Emulator 2.0.0:

  The now 'deprecated' UI showed all three Storage Emulator correctly running. (I can't attach a         snapshot showing it because I've already upgraded the Windows Azure Storage SDK tools for VisualStudio 2013.
- When using Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.2.0:

  [Here was a snapshot showing it is correctly running but I have no reputation to add imgaes :s]

2- Code:

```
        string azureStorageConnectionString = "UseDevelopmentStorage=true";
        string queueName = "queuetest";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
        _queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
        _queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

3- I Got two different problems with each one of the WAS Emulator versions.

-Problem A: On the line _queue.CreateIfNotExists(); got a uri not found exception (404) because it couldn't find the queue, with the uri: 127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1/queuetest

-Problem B: When I upgraded the WAS Emulator the exception was gone (So upgrading was **solution to problem A**) but the Azure Storage Explorer wouldn't access the Developer Storage Account and gave the following message:

```
Windows Azure Developer Storage is not runnign.
The process DSService.exe is not detected
```

So, in summary, I fixed problem A but now **I can't access DevStorage** Account by using Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: Regarding Problem B, it looks like it is specific to Azure Storage Explorer. In the previous versions of Storage Emulator, the name of the service was `DSService.exe` which has been changed to `WAStorageEmulator.exe` in version 3.0+. Please check if you can connect to storage emulator using Visual Studio. HTH.

Comment: That's a very good alternative to view the queue content (I tried to use before but it didn't work till now). So yeah, I think I could go on with that. I'll see if it's the same as using the explorer and if it is, I'll use it instead :-D

Thank you very much for your answer! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mate gave me an astonishing solution. You need to create a VisualStudio project called DSService, place it anywhere in C: and containing the following code:

```
namespace DSService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I can create, insert messages and access the DevStorage account queue using Azure Storage Explorer... :-0

> Update:
>
> As Gaurav Mantri said, you should  use VisualStudio 2013 tools to see
>   the content of your DevStorage account.

Comment: You don't want to do that. Instead, take the source code for Azure Storage Explorer from CodePlex and remove the code which looks for DSService, compile it and use that version.